# Does AWS Elastic Beanstalk Swap Environment Url swaps environments for git push?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have read the docs for zero downtime on aws but cant seem to understand what happens in this scenario?

- I have a environment running in production called 'red'
- I duplicate the environment as 'blue'
- I use eb init on my app to push to the new environment called blue.
- My new version goes up and running on blue environment successfully
- I swap the environment urls ( I havent done this, scared, I guess )
- After a while my traffic gets directed to blue and red will show zero traffic in monitoring.
  The question is **Now if i use *git aws.push* from my command line will it push to red or blue?**

If it pushes to red, I have a process for zero downtime. If it pushed to blue, does that mean I have to eb init again?

If I have to eb init again it means

- Destroy the red (old) environment
- Duplicate the blue as red
- eb init for red environment again

This does not seem to be correct at all. I may be missing something. What is the correct way to do zero downtime on ebs? I have read lots but cant seem to get these points. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup aws.push using aws.config you setup the application and the environment you want to push to, see below:

```
AWS Access Key [default to ]:
AWS Secret Key [default to ]:
AWS Region [default to eu-west-1]:
AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application [default to your-application]: 
AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment [default to red]:
```

All you'd need to do is run, **git aws.config** again and change your *AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment* to equal **blue**.

What I suggest you do is create a **red2** environment by copying your current **red** environments config (*under actions >> save config*) and then applying the config when you build **red2**. Then push you code using **git aws.push** into the **blue** environment, test and then using the Application Versions page promote the code running on **blue** onto **red2**.

Meanwhile all live traffic is still hitting **red**.

You can then use your hosts file or just test the **red2** elastic beanstalk URL make sure everything is in order and then hit the URL swap.

You'll swap **RED** and **RED2**

Comment: btw I wrote a simple tool to avoid to have messing with eb init. I'd be interested in feedback: http://github.com/ingenieux/goploy